# result scope function not displayed in another one angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I don't understand why I can not take the value from a function and to display it in another in angular. My code:

```
$scope.getLatitudeLongitude = function(address) {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            $scope.latLng = [];
            geocoder.geocode( { "address": address }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length > 0) {
                    var location = results[0].geometry.location,
                        lat      = location.lat(),
                        lng      = location.lng();
                    $scope.latLng.push(lat,lng);
                    return $scope.latLng;
                }

            });
};


$scope.save = function () {

            $scope.address = $scope.getAddress();
            $scope.getLatitudeLongitude($scope.address).then(function(){
                console.log($scope.latLng);
            })
 }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: $scope.getLatitudeLongitude() should return a promise. Check what it is returning now. It is returning an array.

Comment: what doesnt work?/

Comment: ok. you dont have  a promise to use then

Comment: This code is all in the same controller right?

Comment: looks like $scope.getLatitudeLongitude($scope.address) is normal function. No need of then to call in your code.

Comment: @MikeFeltman yes

Comment: @IleNea check with my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding  a promise to getLatitudeLogitude like this should work. Inject `$q` too in controller

```
$scope.getLatitudeLongitude = function(address) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                $scope.latLng = [];
                geocoder.geocode( { "address": address }, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length > 0) {
                        var location = results[0].geometry.location,
                            lat      = location.lat(),
                            lng      = location.lng();
                        $scope.latLng.push(lat,lng);
                       deferred.resolve($scope.latLng);
                    }
                    else{
                         // geocode error
                     deferred.reject();
                  }

                }
               return deferred.promise;

    };


$scope.save = function () {

           $scope.address = $scope.getAddress();
           $scope.getLatitudeLongitude($scope.address)
                .then(function(latLng){
                     console.log(latLng);
                },function(){
                     //log your error here;
                };
};
```

Comment: it gives me error saying: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: did u click on the error and find out which line is the error

Comment: @IleNea can you check now. the geocode success call back was not in the way I expected it to be

Comment: Thank you very much, for look at this bug: if for example I write this: $scope.getLatitudeLongitude($scope.address).then(function(latLng){
                    console.log($scope.val = latLng[0]);
                });
                
                 console.log($scope.val);  -> the $scope.val is undefined... why is happening?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150192/discussion-between-jins-peter-and-ilenea).

Answer (score 0):

```
    $scope.getLatitudeLongitude = function(address) {
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                $scope.latLng = [];
                geocoder.geocode( { "address": address }, function(results, status) {
                    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length > 0) {
                        var location = results[0].geometry.location,
                            lat      = location.lat(),
                            lng      = location.lng();
                        $scope.latLng.push(lat,lng);
                        //return $scope.latLng; you don't need to return when the method execute the $scope will know and keep the value visible to $scope.save
                    }

                });
    };

    $scope.getAddress = function(){
//perform your scope.getAddress process here and after you get your address do this
$scope.addressRecieved = addressReturned;
      };

    $scope.save = function () {

              //  $scope.address = $scope.getAddress();
$scope.address = $scope.addressRecieved;
if($scope.address !== undefined) {               
   $scope.getLatitudeLongitude($scope.address);
}else{
console.log('Address not defined!');
}
         console.log($scope.latLng);           

     }
```

//trigger the $scope.getAddress first, you can even call the $scope.save inside the $scope.getAddress method, to ensure that the address is always defined else this programme won't work as expected.
//You can even use callback e.g function(){$scope.getAddress, callback}